# time loop c# while/if

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I need help with a loop in C#. What the loop needs to do:

xt = 50

Now the program needs to wait the time (x = 50), decrementing it every second. If the actual time is 0, the program needs to send my request and set `xt = 50`. So the loop can start again, all in all this piece of code should check every 50 seconds to sent a request to the server.

My actual code:

```
while (xt != 0)
{
    xt--;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine ("bla:"+ xt);
}

if (xt == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ich sende!");
    //post.SendPost(randomengine.decodeb64(URL2),"Alive");//richtige Daten eintragen! Idiot!
    xt = 50;
}
```

Comment: You're using decimating while loops to do timing? what guarantee do you have that your `xt` variable will be decremented every second instead of thousands of times per second?

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000) waits for 50 seconds (50000 ms)

Comment: That does mean your entire thread will grind to a halt for 50 seconds.

Comment: This code could be replaced by `for (int xt = 50; xt != 0; --xt) { Console.WriteLine("bla:" + xt); } Console.WriteLine("Ich sende!");`.  And that isn't going to wait 50 seconds.

Comment: @cHao how does that solve anything?

Comment: A nice Example of your problem is given here ..try that out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx

Comment: @TimothyGroote: It doesn't.  That's kinda my point -- the loop on its own does nothing towards waiting for any length of time.

Answer (score 6):

```
 DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
        tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50);
        tmr.Start();
        tmr.Tick += (sndr, ex) =>
            {
                //send request 
            };
```

I hope this helps, this Tick event will fire after every 50 seconds

Comment: You might add the `Tick` handler before starting the timer, for correctness's sake.  (That looks like a race condition, though the chances of it affecting anything are exceedingly slim.)

Comment: @cHao yes you are right, this would have caused problem if time interval was too small.

Answer (score 1):

Place you `if` block in `while` loop. Add `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in your while loop, and change `xt = xt` to `xt = 50` in you `if` check.

And you can also use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000)` instead of `while` loop as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Why -1?? It is not the best, but still a solution of the problem.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this. it could work. It's not the prettiest solution but hey.

Comment: i updated code in first post. the if block doesn't restart :( any idea why?

Comment: @JanisHeller your if block must be in your while loop

Comment: @TimothyGroote: In fact, it's one of the ugliest solutions in pretty much all cases.  The only uglier ones would be busy-waiting or creating a Form (in a service or something) for the sole purpose of using the forms timer.

Comment: Oh i agree that it's ugly, but since it's a possible solution, not worth a downvote.

Comment: if you'v got a better solution just post :o)

Comment: @JanisHeller the best solution is 5 voted answer here (using `Timer`). Choose it, and use it

Comment: my current project is cmd based, is there a easy option to get the namespace of the timer in cmd based codes? just "using System.Threading;" seems not to fit

Comment: @JanisHeller Use `System.Timers.Timer` class

Comment: using System.Timers.Timer; seems not to be an using statement

Comment: @JanisHeller i already wrote that it is a class. directly create its object

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer, eg. [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). There are other timers in .Net Framework, but according to your question this one seems to be the most appropriate.